# set a variable with a return value of a query

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

Hi I have something like this in my store procedure,

```
SET @SQl = 'Some query' --this query return only a cell the type int
SET @VAR = exec(@SQL) --the varaible @var it's local and the type int
```

How can i get the return value of the query and set to the variable, it's possible?? or what I'm doing it's wrong???

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the query returns a scalar result set you need to do

```
DECLARE @VAR INT

DECLARE @Result TABLE
(
C INT
)

DECLARE @SQl NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQl = 'SELECT 1'

INSERT INTO @Result
EXEC(@SQl)

SELECT @VAR = C FROM @Result
```

Much better to use `sp_executesql` and `OUTPUT` parameters

```
DECLARE @VAR INT

DECLARE @SQl NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQl = 'SELECT @out = 1'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQl, N'@out int output', @out = @VAR OUTPUT

SELECT @VAR
```

Comment: good but i have another question how i set in query like this a parameters of out `select count(idTable) from table` ?? maybe like this `select count(idTable) = @out from table`

Comment: @Jorge - `select @out = count(idTable)`

Comment: @Jorge - Yes it does. Not sure how you expect me to diagnose what you're doing wrong from that information!

Comment: i'm posting in this link the code associated with the problem and well thanks for asking my first question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899265/where-is-the-problem

Comment: You can't chain together multiple `EXEC` calls like that.