# where is the problem

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I new transact sql i'm stock with this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Example 
    @MAESTRDESC varchar(50) --Contiene el valor a ingresar por pantalla
AS
/****Vars*****/
DECLARE
    @Result TABLE
    (
        ClientesDisponibles int,
        ClientesAgendados   int
    )
DECLARE
    @SQL varchar(500),--Guarda la cantidad de clientes disponibles
    @SQLAGENDADOS varchar(500)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT COUNT(idtable) from table';
SET @SQL = 'SELECT COUNT(idtable2) from table2';

INSERT INTO @Result EXEC @SQL, EXEC@SQLAGENDADOS;

SELECT 
    R.ClientesDisponibles,
    R.ClientesAgendados 
FROM 
    @Result R
RETURN
```

**EDIT**
 the exception say's

`Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.`

give's and exception but i don't have any idea about what i'm doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Here's one for sure: you're declaring @SQL as an INT, but then trying to set it equal to a string.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli sorry my mistake posting the question i'm already edited

Comment: You shoulodl be using dynamic SQl as a last resort not a first try. There is no need for dynamic sql in this at all. Please read the following link and do not consider writing any dynamic SQl again until you truly understand it: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't chain together multiple `EXEC` calls like that and you are missing parentheses (and Neil's point too!)

You could do

```
INSERT INTO @Result(ClientesDisponibles) 
EXEC (@SQL)

INSERT INTO @Result(ClientesAgendados) 
EXEC (@SQLAGENDADOS)
```

This will insert 2 separate rows though. No idea why you aren't using `sp_executesql` for this [as per your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897799/set-a-variable-with-a-return-value-of-a-query/5897868#5897868).

Comment: @Martin i can't use another store procedure for matters off company where i work, something else it's possible to make the insert in the same row?? thanks for asking i really helpful

Comment: @Jorge - Does this need to be dynamic SQL at all? If so can you combine the 2 dynamic SQL scripts together into one script? `SELECT (SELECT COUNT(idtable) from table), (SELECT COUNT(idtable2) from table2)`

Comment: @Martin unfortunately it's have to be a dynamic query, but i don't see how can i combine the two queries

Comment: @Jorge - If they are both returning a single value and are a single statement then you can just do `SELECT (query1), (query2)` Otherwise you could just assign to variables inside the combined dynamic SQL script and do `SELECT @VAR1, @VAR2` at the end.

Comment: @Martin don't work because the variables are varchar and if do the select just prints the querys but no executes the query itself

Comment: @Martin finally i see your point and i solved mi problem thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

It won't work because of this line:

`DECLARE    @SQL int`

You need to declare `@SQL` as a `VARCHAR` in order to use it as a `string`.  The same goes for `@SQLAGENDADOS`.

However, you should also see @Martins answer regarding chaining multiple executes.

Why don't you do the following:

```
DECLARE @Count1 INT;
DECLARE @Count2 INT;

SELECT @Count1 = COUNT(idtable) 
  FROM table;

SELECT @Count2 = COUNT(idtable2) 
  FROM table2;

INSERT INTO @Result 
     VALUES (@Count1, @Count2);
```

Comment: that's not the problem it's was a problem posting the question but i fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Example 
@MAESTRDESC varchar(50) --Contiene el valor a ingresar por pantalla
    AS
/****Vars*****/
DECLARE
    @Result TABLE
    (
        ClientesDisponibles int,
        ClientesAgendados   int
    )
DECLARE
    @SQL int,--Guarda la cantidad de clientes disponibles
    @SQLAGENDADOS int

SELECT @SQL = COUNT(idtable) from [table]
SELECT @SQLAGENDADOS = COUNT(idtable2) from [table2]

INSERT @Result VALUES (@SQL, @SQLAGENDADOS)

SELECT 
    R.ClientesDisponibles,
    R.ClientesAgendados 
FROM 
    @Result R
RETURN
```